# Pass-through an Android device connected via USB to a VM in Azure

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, android, azure

I'm running android studio in a VM on Azure. I can't get emulators to work at all though even though i have nested virtualization so I'm trying a pass-through approach.

I'm able to get the VM to see my PCs drives and even see my device as a MTP device to access its files. I haven't gotten the VM to see it as a phone though. Is there a way to pass-through my device to the VM, so its seen as a phone (so that android studio will run on it)

I've run through RemoteFX a ton, ensuring that its enabled and that USB redirection is turned on to no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For app development access to the the device you need `adb`. Adb by default only works via USB, but you can activate adb via IP by issuing the following command on a PC that has an Android device connected via USB (and activated developer options & adb):

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

This opens TCP port 5555 on the device for connections, e.g. via Wifi.

Hence if you manager to make the adb tcp port visible to your cloud system a connection would be possible.

**Please not that an adb connection via IP has absolutely no security! Adb can be seen equivalent to telnet from a security perspective.**

Hence I strongly recommend to tunnel it, e.g. using SSH port forwarding in a SSH connection between your local PC and the cloud instance (forward a selected TCP port on the cloud instance to port 5555 using the IP address of the Android phone in your local network.

Once the port forwarding is established you can execute on the cloud instance

```
adb connect localhost:<forwarded TCP port>
```

and the remote device will become visible for Android Studio.

Comment: This would be an excellent answer if you specify the command to do the ssh tunnel

Comment: @CompEng88 Sorry I mainly use Windows and thus use Putty where I have a UI for configuring my SSH connections.

Comment: I've tried OpenSSH Server on Windows 11 and while I can create and route the tunnel, adb on the remote end fails to properly connect even though they're the same version. As of 2023 I don't think this works, but hopefully someone can figure it out and update you answer since this is a pretty great idea if it works!